# android fragment display sqlite data in list

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I am trying to display a list from a SQLite database in a fragment. 
I have tried it using an activity and it was succesfull, but using fragment I can't make it work using a fragment.

```
public class AppleFragment extends ListFragment {

    /** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
    String apple_versions[] = new String[]{
        "Mountain Lion",
        "Lion",
        "Snow Leopard",
        "Leopard",
        "Tiger"

    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity().getBaseContext(),  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, apple_versions);

        /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }

}
```

This is just an example, I want to turn it into a SQLite list and display it in a fragment.

Comment: A small note: you do not have to call `getActivity().getBaseContext()` where you create the `ArrayAdapter`, as `Activity` already extends from `Context`.

Comment: Follow [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) documentation.

Comment: following documentation, still not succesfull with this is there any simple example to follow. also sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override 
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, apple_versions);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Don't use onCreateView, use onActivityCreated or onViewCreated method of the fragment to load the list.

Comment: used onViewCreated method but not able to populate list of fragment from sqlite database looking for simple example if there any available.